# xml empty tags with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

```
$xmlFile="<test>WPUBON</test>
    <test1>SAPRTA</test1>
    <test2></test2>
    <test3></test3> ";
```

I have a String as above and i'm parsing this using PHP `DOMDocuments`

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->loadXML($xmlFile);
$xml->save("out/".$xmlFileName.".xml");
```

The output of empty tags comes as `</test2>` which i need to be `<test2></test2>` due to the application which process this xml needed as that.

Please let me know a way to do this !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the manual page of [`DOMDocument::save()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.save.php). It supports the option [`LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/libxml.constants.php). Try this:

```
$xml->save("out/".$xmlFileName.".xml", LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG );
```