# How to prevent DOMDocument from creating self closing tags?

Tags: php, rss, domdocument

I want to create an RSS feed with DOMDocument on PHP.

The problem is that `createElement("link", "example.com");` creates a self-closing `<link>` tag like in html.

How do I create a `<link></link>` that is necessary for making an RSS feed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xml empty tags with PHP DOMDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183296/xml-empty-tags-with-php-domdocument)

Comment: `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` option didn't help. I tried it before asking a question. Actually, adding `header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', true);` solved my problem.